# Angular 7: Test fail for one component is related to a different component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am testing a component but the test fails, but the reason for the failure is related to a different component which I have not declared in the test:

```
FooterComponent should create
Failed: Component SplashComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

[image]

FooterComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  public date: number;
  public brandName: string;

  constructor(
    private config: Configuration) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.brandName = this.config.getConfigOption('brandName');
    this.date = new Date().getFullYear();
  }

}
```

Test:

```
describe('FooterComponent', () => {
  let component: FooterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)
      ],
      declarations: [FooterComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

NGModule for reference:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SplashComponent,
    FooterComponent,
   .....
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
   .....
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This same issue is repeated for tests for other components.

EDIT: Answers mention footer template containing child components, they do not. However if I add SplashComponent to test declaration it does work, but then another component takes its place.

[image]

Something somewhere is creating a hierarchy.

Footer template:

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="links">
        <ul>
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/support']">Support</a></li>
          <li><a [routerLink]="['/terms']">Terms & Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="copyright">
        <p>
          &copy; {{ date }} {{ brandName}}. Made with <span class="icon-favourites"></span> by 
          <a href="" target="_blank"></a>.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

EDIT: 2

App.component template:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</main>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that you are importing the `RouterTestingModule` with routes, most likely with a path associated to the `SplashComponent`.

Unless you plan to test specific routes with concrete components, you shouldnt configure routes on the `RouterTestingModule`. Refactor into the following:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [FooterComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks. It does not contain a child component, however declaring it in the test bed does work. Other component takes the place of splash component (see update). Is there another mechanism that would create a hierarchical relationship with unrelated compoments?

Answer (score 1):

With your test, you can import directly the children component in your test OR you can mock the children components. See:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
     ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent,
    MockSplashComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})

... 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asplash-component',
  template: ''
})
export class MockSplashComponent{

}
```

Comment: Thanks. The FooterComponent is treating other (unrelated) components as child components. I am not sure what is causing this. I have updated the question with Footer template.

Comment: Strange, so you seems to import all your module declaration from somewhere. Are you sure that you only have `RouterTestingModule` in your import ?

Comment: In the test bed for Footer? Yes only RouterTestingModule. The issue is replicated with other components as well.

Comment: I have no clue, sorry.

Comment: I was passing routes object! Thanks for help.

Comment: AAAAh right. That was this module. Endeed, it's `RouterTestingModule`. Nice catch.